# How to copy subsequent text after matching a pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with each line look something like this -

```
GeneralBKT_n24_-e_dee_testcaseid_blt12_0001_s3_n4
```

Each line has keyword `testcaseid` followed by some test case id (in this case `blt12_0001` is the id and `s3` and `n4` are some parameters). I want to extract `blt12_0001` from the above line. Each testcaseid will have exactly 1 underscore '_' in-between. What would be a regex for this case and how can I store name of test case id in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of capturing groups:

```
testcaseid_([^_]+_[^_]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/apCfxv/1/).

---

One of many possible ways in `Python` could be

```
import re

line = "GeneralBKT_n24_-e_dee_testcaseid_blt12_0001_s3_n4"

for id in re.finditer(r'testcaseid_([^_]+_[^_]+)', line):
    print(id.group(1))
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/9U5tQM).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to capture your testcaseid given in your format,

```
(?<=testcaseid_)[^_]+_[^_]+
```

This essentially captures a text having exactly one underscore between them and preceded by `testcaseid_` text using positive lookbehind. Here `[^_]+` captures one or more any character other than underscore, followed by `_` then again uses `[^_]+` to capture one or more any character except `_`

[Check out this demo](https://regex101.com/r/AS9IaK/1)

Check out this Python code,

```
import re

list = ['GeneralBKT_n24_-e_dee_testcaseid_blt12_0001_s3_n4', 'GeneralBKT_n24_-e_dee_testcaseid_blt12_0001_s6_n9']

for s in list:
 grp = re.search(r'(?<=testcaseid_)[^_]+_[^_]+', s)
 if grp:
  print(grp.group())
```

Output,

```
blt12_0001
blt12_0001
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option that might work would be:

```
import re
expression = r"[^_\r\n]+_[^_\r\n]+(?=(?:_[a-z0-9]{2}){2}$)"

string = '''

GeneralBKT_n24_-e_dee_testcaseid_blt12_0001_s3_n4
GeneralBKT_n24_-e_dee_testcaseid_blt81_0023_s4_n5

'''

print(re.findall(expression, string, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['blt12_0001', 'blt81_0023']
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vqqlzt/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vqqlzt/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/vqqlzt/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---